# How to Update this mobile no field to firestore database when all the data have route to this screen

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-router, react-native

How do i update this mobile no field to firestore database i am unable to find the doc id. i tried many times but it showing me error that doc id is missing which doc id should i have to put please make a help for me in this case. Thankyou.

```
const ItemDetails = ({ route }) => {
    const[values, setValue] = useState('')
    let data = route.params
    console.log(data)

    const updateValue = () => {
        db.collection("FinalData")
            .doc()
            .update({ 
                mobile_no: values
            })
            .then(function () {
                alert("Mobile Number Updated Successfully")
            })
    }
```

Comment: You didn't specify a document ID, so you are getting a random ID.  That document surely does not exist.

Comment: Sir i have tried many things in that parenthesis like data.id, data.doc.id,   item.id,   route.id like this but it is not updating always giving me same error like  doc is missing. It is a routed navigation screen so doc id is not getting defined. if i fetch data on one screen then i would be possible to update the field. but is a routed screen which doc id should i have to put..?????

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you do not know which doc id to put.

In Firestore, you can only update an existing document.

Right now, what you want to do with this line `db.collection("FinalData").doc().update(...)` is to update a document, but you have not told firestore which document to remove the old mobile no from and put the new mobile no in.

Another way to understand this is we can assume that your firestore database is a book. What you want to do with this line `db.collection("FinalData").doc().update(...)` is to tell firestore to please change mobile no to 'bla bla bla' on page (you didn't give any page number). So you see, firestore can not change anything because it does not which page to change.

So the doc id being referred to is the id of the document you want to correct.

This mobile no, is probably one of your users mobile number, so get the document (which could be something like user-settings, user-details or so) id.

Then you put that document id as shown below:

`db.collection("FinalData").doc('PUT-DOC-ID-HERE').update(...)`

Comment: Thank you for responding. there are many docs available in database if i do manually then i will take like my 7 days to update the docs. that is why i have done what when the details of the customer clicked it will take that selected details and it is doing well also i just want to update the doc id of the selected customer which i am not getting. is there any other way to do that ?????????

Comment: i know i am very close to that but it is a routed screen so it is bit difficult for me to update the details of that document.

Comment: "... when the details of the customer clicked it will take that selected details..." the selected details should have the id of the customer. If you can post the full code, I will show you how to pass it.

Comment: You are not meant to write the id manually. You are meant to pass it to your function. Post the full code.